# I made a function, I want to export its value JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Next folks ... I'm learning JS so I apologize right now.

I did a function on a file, using REQUEST that it takes information from the corona virus.

I am also using venom-bot to use whatsapp and send this information.

In the file "API.JS" I have this code:

```js
const request = require('request');

pesquisa = function pesquisa(uf, infoCorona){
request.get(`https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/uf/${uf}`, (error,response,body)=> {
    if(!error){
        var resultado = JSON.parse(body)
        var data = [...resultado.datetime.split('-')]
        infoCorona = `Estado:  ${resultado.state}\nUF: ${resultado.uf}\nCasos: ${resultado.cases}\nMortes confirmadas: ${resultado.deaths}\nInformações atualizadas: ${data[2].slice(0, 2) - 1}/${data[1]}/${data[0]} no horário: ${data[2].slice(3, 11)}`
        console.log(infoCorona)
    }else{
        console.log(error)
    }
    return infoCorona
})
}
exports.pesquisa = pesquisa;
```

it returns me exactly what I need. However, I have another file with this code:

```js
const api = require('./api.js')

// Supports ES6
// import { create, Whatsapp } from 'venom-bot';
const venom = require('venom-bot');
 
venom
  .create()
  .then((client) => start(client))
  .catch((erro) => {
    console.log(erro);
  });
 
function start(client) {
  client.onMessage((message) => {
    mensagem = message.body.split(' ')
    if (mensagem.slice(0, 2).join(' ') === 'corona virus' && message.isGroupMsg === false){
      estado = mensagem.slice(2,3)
      api.pesquisa(`${estado}`)
      client.sendText(message.from, `${infoCorona}`)//info Send
      console.log(estado)
    }
    console.log(mensagem.slice(0, 2).join(' '))
  });
}
```

I want that after the parameter "message.from" it brings me the information recorded in "message" of the file api.js. (first code.) How do I do this?

I still have a problem: /

Comment: I copied and pasted the code for testing, but the venom-bot does not send as much information as I want ... In fact, it does nothing. (Index.js page). Do you have any idea what it is? It doesn't print anything on the terminal either. @loremdipso

Answer (score 1):

Your API call is asynchronous, which means you have to wait until the data gets returned before you can use it. In JavaScript you do this with a `Promise`. A `Promise` allows you to provide a callback to its `then` function which will get called when the data is returned. For you, that might look something like:

```
pesquisa = function pesquisa(uf) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(`https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/uf/${uf}`, (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error) {
                var resultado = JSON.parse(body)
                var data = [...resultado.datetime.split('-')]
                infoCorona = `Estado:  ${resultado.state}\nUF: ${resultado.uf}\nCasos: ${resultado.cases}\nMortes confirmadas: ${resultado.deaths}\nInformações atualizadas: ${data[2].slice(0, 2) - 1}/${data[1]}/${data[0]} no horário: ${data[2].slice(3, 11)}`
                console.log(infoCorona)
                resolve(infoCorona);
            } else {
                console.log(error)
                reject(Error("It broke"));
            }
        });
    });
}

...

function start(client) {
    client.onMessage((message) => {
        mensagem = message.body.split(' ')
        if (mensagem.slice(0, 2).join(' ') === 'corona virus' && message.isGroupMsg === false) {
            estado = mensagem.slice(2, 3)
            api.pesquisa(`${estado}`).then((infoCorona) => {
                client.sendText(message.from, `${infoCorona}`)//info Send
                console.log(estado)
            });
        }
        console.log(mensagem.slice(0, 2).join(' '))
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code for testing, but the venom-bot does not send as much information as I want ... In fact, it does nothing. (Index.js page). Do you have any idea what it is? It doesn't print anything on the terminal either.

Comment: try adding some `console.log()`'s to see where execution stops. Is `pesquisa` called? Are there any errors on the network tab?

Comment: I located console.log () to see where the program stops, and it stops at the line where api.pesquisa () is triggered.

Do you have any idea why? @loremdipso